# Java while loop, can't use oop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have to write a program using while loops asking for what birds the user has seen and how many, those questions get repeated until the user inputs END and the loop stops allowing it to print two messages, one of them having the most common bird with the name and number. The program works but when printing out the last two messages, instead of printing the name of that bird it prints the word END. I know I need a variable to store the common bird but I don't know how to do that. Listed below is the code.

```
{
    String BirdName;
    String CommonBird="";
    int NumberOfTimes;
    int mostNumberOfTimes = 0;
    String quite =  "END";

    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Which bird have you seen?");
        BirdName = Scanner.nextLine();

        if (BirdName.equals(quite))
        {
            System.out.println("You saw "+ mostNumberOfTimes + " " + BirdName+ ".");
            System.out.println("It was the most common bird seen at one time in your garden.");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("How many were in your garden at once?");
            NumberOfTimes = Integer.parseInt(Scanner.nextLine());

            if(mostNumberOfTimes < NumberOfTimes)
            {
                mostNumberOfTimes = NumberOfTimes;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to add another variable and store bird seen by user into that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need another variable for recording the most common bird. You can assign to `CommonBird` at the same time that you update `mostNumberOfTimes`, and then use it in your output statement.

```
String birdName;
String commonBird = "";
int numberOfTimes;
int mostNumberOfTimes = 0;
String quit = "END";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Which bird have you seen?");
    birdName = scanner.nextLine();

    if (birdName.equals(quit)) {
        System.out.println("You saw " + mostNumberOfTimes +
                           " " + commonBird + ".");
        System.out.println("It was the most common bird seen" +
                           " at one time in your garden.");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("How many were in your garden at once?");
        numberOfTimes = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        if (mostNumberOfTimes < numberOfTimes) {
            mostNumberOfTimes = numberOfTimes;
            commonBird = birdName; // added this
        }
    }
}
```

Variable names should always start with a lowercase letter according the Java style guides. Only class names should have a capitalized first letter.